# How to turn off depth sensor completely in realsense D435?

Tags: realsense

I know the point of the realsense is the depth image, but is there any way to just turn off the depth camera completely for a while? I'm using the c++ api. Python's fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to disable the depth stream before starting the camera. Also you can configure the streams as per your requirement.

```
rs2::config config;
config.disable_stream(RS2_STREAM_DEPTH); // disable depth streams

rs2::pipeline pipeline;
rs2::pipeline_profile pipeline_profile;

pipeline_profile = pipeline.start(config); //  start camera

while(true)
{
    rs2::frameset current_frameset = pipeline.wait_for_frames(); //get all synched frames
    rs2::video_frame current_rgb_frame   = current_frameset.get_color_frame();// get rgb frame
    ..
    ..
}
```